# Won't start with a new battery and won't turn over or make any noise

Tags: electrical, starting

[image: Picture of truck]

This is a 1986 Ford F-150. It won't start or crank over.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information than that. The more effort you put into your question, the higher the quality of answers you'll get. Do any of the electrics work?

Comment: Do headlights or interior dome lights work? Do any of the dashboard warning lights come on when the key is turned to the ignition position?

Comment: blown starter motor? Seized engine? Ignition switch busted? This really could be anything.

Comment: Please add more information about your problem. You have to put some effort to collect some information about the problem. Is that a manual or automatic gear? Did you try these? -> http://www.wikihow.com/Test-a-Starter-Solenoid

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the alternator or maybe loose/bad cable connection? Installed correctly/completely? These are only my guesses.